# Linq on XML get value from nested elements in select

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this XML code on which I do a select statement with linq. But I have problems geting a nested value role.

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>
      <fn>Donald Duck</fn>
      <n>
        <family>Duck</family>
        <given>Donald</given>
      </n>
    </name>
    <email />
    <tel teltype="voice" />
    <tel teltype="mobile" />
    <adr>
    </adr>
    <institutionrole roletype="Employee" />
    <extension>
      <institutions>
        <institution institution="Division1">
          <role>sales</role>
        </institution>
        <institution institution="Division2">
          <role>observer</role>
        </institution>
      </institutions>
    </extension>
  </person>
</persons>
```

I select all persons and filter on for instance institution=Division1
Then I want the value for role on that institution.

My code so far but the let role = does'nt work

```
var users = (from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("person")
let role = person.Element("extension").Descendants("institutions").SingleOrDefault(ins => ins.Elements("institution").Attribute("institution").Value.ToLower() == units).Select(ins => ins.Element("role")).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
 where person.Element("extension").Descendants("institutions").Elements("institution").Attributes("institution").Where(ins => ins.Value.ToLower() == units).Any();
select new User(){
      userRole = role,
      UserLastname = person.Element("name").Element("n").Element("family").Value,
      UserFirstname = person.Element("name").Element("n").Element("given").Value
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: is the first `</persons>` meant to be `<persons>`?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does actually happen? Do you get an exception or the value returned is null?

Comment: I wouldn't expect `ins.Elements("institution").Attribute("institution").Value` to work - that's trying to get a *single* attribute value from *multiple* elements. What do you expect it to do? (I wouldn't expect it to compile, to be honest.)

Comment: I fixed the start of the XML and the indentation, but it's still clear what you're trying to achieve, especially given that you're comparing  both the role and the insitution attribute to `units`. Could you give a clear example of what you're expecting as a result here? At that point it should be easier to help you - and probably to make the code easier to read, as well.

Comment: There are several persons in the xml. I want to list persons on a specific institution with their role.

List:
Donald Duck, sales
Winnie Poe, customerCare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've rewritten your query completely so that we end up with the `institution` element and the `n` element, rather than trying to find the role directly in a `let` clause. I think this ends up as a far simpler query. I'd also say that using vertical space is easier to read than creating very long lines - although that's subjective.

I've used the explicit conversions from `XAttribute` and `XElement` to `string` rather than using the `Value` property. This works "better" (depending on what you're trying to achieve) with missing elements (where we end up with a null value rather than an exception) and I find it easier to read. Again, it's somewhat subjective.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var targetInstitution = "Division1";

        var users =
            from person in doc.Root.Elements("person")
            let name = person.Element("name").Element("n")
            let institution = person
                .Element("extension")
                .Elements("institutions")
                .Elements("institution")
                .SingleOrDefault(ins => (string) ins.Attribute("institution") == targetInstitution)
            // Only include users where we've foudn the institution
            where institution != null
            select new
            {
                UserRole = (string) institution.Element("role"),
                UserFirstName = (string) name.Element("given"),
                UserLastName = (string) name.Element("family")
            };

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Output with your test file:

```
{ UserRole = sales, UserFirstName = Donald, UserLastName = Duck }
```

Comment: @JohnyL: I did state: "I've used the explicit conversions from XAttribute and XElement to string rather than using the Value property."

Answer (score 0):

the follwing code will return all roles in `institution` element that it's attribute `institution` equal to `division1`

```
 var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(args[0]);
 var institution = xmlDoc.Descendants("institution");
 var roles = institution.Where(x => 
                    x.Attribute("institution").Value.ToLower() == "division1").Elements();
 foreach (var xElement in roles)
 {
     // Do your business here working with ======>>   xElement.Value
 }
```

Hope this help you.